# How wifi symbol bars are calibrated?

Tags: wireless-networking

On your laptop/computer screen, you can see the wifi symbol, it consists of 4 curved bars. Lesser the number of bars glowing, lesser is the signal strength. How these bars are calibrated? I mean does each bar represents say 20db, so that when number of bars glowing goes down from 4 to 3, that would mean your device is receiving 20db lesser signal strength.

Comment: They are not calibrated in any way, every manufacturer does whatever pleases him.

Comment: Signal strength bars are nothing but a "feel good" thing, they make you feel good and give you comfort, they are no real representation of signal strength.

Comment: @acejsvelin This is not quite correct. The bars do represent signal strength in as much as more bars is more signal strength. The bars are comparable on the same device, but not neccessarily between different ones.

Comment: @davidgo how to convert no of bars to signal strength?

Comment: Get software which measures the signal strength as a number (ie in dBm) - within the same device this will tell you signal strength above the noise floor.

Answer (score 4):

The bars are a lie. There's no industry standard for how to light them up. On some platforms they're calibrated to generate the fewest support calls.

If your software gives you an RSSI number in negative dBm, that's usually less of a lie but still not terribly reliable.

Comment: Is there any online resource to confirm the same? @Spiff

Comment: I'm not sure how you might want me to demonstrate that there is no standard. You could download IEEE 802.11-2012 yourself and read/search through it until you're convinced it doesn't say anything about signal strength bar icons. You could do the same with the the Wi-Fi Alliance's documentation as well, if they still make it available without a membership. You could download all the open source curved bar icon Wi-Fi signal meters you can find and read through their source code and see that there's no consistency.

Comment: @AmitMaurya Well, for a start, many devices can pro grammatically set the levels for each bar - my uniquity NanoStation WIFI AP has user programable threshholds for each part of the signal bar.   This makes a lot of sense as these bars are simply a software interpretation of a raw signal strenght indicator presented by your card.